# Same Theme across all android-powered devices

Tags: android

So i currently have a low-end Samsung Galaxy Pocket smartphone which uses the factory version of Android 2.3. When i test my apps in this device, it uses the gingerbread theme which is ugly. Android 4.2 UI is very nice and cool. So I want to know how to use the theme of Android 4.2 when im using lower versions of android. Here are some comparisons:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the holo theme, you can use this library: [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere). Alternatively, you can also create you're own theme.

Comment: sir, how can i apply this theme to my app? i already downloaded the zip file and shall i create style folder in the res folder? sorry, beginner here

Comment: You can find [the instructions here](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/wiki/Import-in-IDE#eclipse)